# aws presigned post 400 bad request

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, postman

i'm trying to upload a file through Postman to my bucket.
Im usign a post request so on my nodejs backend i'm generating a presigned post url, by using this function on aws sdk

```
Url() {
    const suffix = `${(0, uuid_1.v4)()}`;
    const extension = path_1.default.basename(this.fileName);
    const params = {
        Bucket: constants_1.BUCKET,
        Fields: {
            Key: `${this.pathToSave}/${suffix}${extension}`,
            "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
        },
        Conditions: [
            ["content-length-range", 0.1, 200000000],
            ["eq", "$x-amz-meta-postid", this.postId],
            ["eq", "$Content-Type", "image/jpeg"]
        ],
        Expires: 180
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        S3.createPresignedPost(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

This is how i'm making the request through postman

[image]

The problem is that when i send the request i'm gettin a 400 Bad Request error. I have read all the aws documentation and searched online, but i'm not understanding how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your conditions change:

["content-length-range", 0.1, 200000000] to ["content-length-range", 1, 200000000]

---

My code that works:

```
const params = {
    Bucket: "{bucket_name}",
    Fields: {
        Key: `test.jpg`,
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
    },
     Conditions: [
        ["content-length-range", 1, 2000000000],
        ["eq", "$x-amz-meta-postid", "some-post-id"],
        ["eq", "$Content-Type", "image/jpeg"]
   ],
    Expires: 380
};

s3.createPresignedPost(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Presigning post data encountered an error', err);
  } else {
    console.log('The post data is', data);
  }
});
```

---

Request to postman:

[image]

Comment: unfortunately same problem, i'm searching from all the day for this problem it seems impossible to detect the problem

Comment: @leaddeveloper With the code that I posted it's working. Can you add a screenshot to the response that you are getting when you changed 0.1 to 1

Comment: the problems is not on nodejs but on aws, when i'm generating this presigned url i need to make a post request on this url so as you can see from my screenshot the request is made on the generated aws url on nodejs, by the way also if you put 0.1 on nodejs it works bcz if you read clearly the problem is not on nodejs

Comment: The presigned url is generated in both cases. But when it's 0.1 and you make a Post request to the presigned url you get Invalid Policy: Invalid JSON and when you change it to 1 it works with 204 No Content.

Comment: are you sending the request through postman

Comment: Yes, I have added the screenshot with the request to Postman.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242865/discussion-between---and-lead-developer).

Comment: actually now works, the problem was also in postman that if i let him calculate the content length not works, but if i set by hand it works